# How do I reference an element of a vector in a conditional?

Tags: r

I am selecting a specific element from a vector at random and then testing if it matches several numbers:

```
counter=0
 variable1=0
    a=c(rep(0,10),11,12,13,14,15,16)
    for (i in 1:1000) {
    num=sample(1:16)
    if(a[num]==11){
      variable_1=11
counter=counter+1
    }
    }
```

When I run this code, I get the following warning: In if (a[num] == 11) { ... :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

What is wrong here?

Comment: Use `replace` instead of`if`. Also please share a few rows of all objs/variables you are using

Comment: Hm, I ran ?replace and it seems like it changes the value in the vector. Is that what it does? As for the code, cc_sample is a vector with 16 elements, num is a random number 1-16, and on the board is an integer that gets redefined throughout the program

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @RonakShah. I have edited the post with what I think is a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Are you sure this line is correct? `a=c(rep(0,10),11,12,13,14,15,16)`.

Comment: It could be wrong, I will check it. Do you have feedback on the if statement?

Comment: num is length 16, so `a[num]` is also length 16.  If you want to sample only 1 element then `num = sample(1:16, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to sample `a` 1000 times with replacement and count the 11's.  A simple way to do that is:

```
a=c(rep(0,10),11,12,13,14,15,16)
allnums <- sample(a, 1000, replace = TRUE)
tot11 <- sum(allnums == 11)
```